# How to tell if a button was pressed in a different key-frame?

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2, movieclip

I'm new to flash development, and i am trying to make is so that when i press a mode button in the game, it changes the speed of the obstacles. The problem is that the obstacles are in a different key-frame, and the code for the speed is within the movie clip itself. How do it tell the obstacles in a different key-frame what their speed should be??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set a variable when a user clicks the mode button.

```
    var speed:Number = 5;

    modeButton.onRelease = function() {
        speed = 10;
    }
```

Then reference that variable later on for your obstacles...

```
    trace("speed: " + speed);
```

This is a super simple example, hope it's helpful!

Comment: the question is labeled as AS2

Comment: He also specified that the code was inside keyframes yet you use class specific identifiers. Also, a variable declared inside a movieclip is not "global". Of a scope that will work for this purpose, yes. But not "global". Your logic works, but that code will not work for him at all.

Comment: Fair enough - I missed the AS2 tag. I'll update to reflect you point.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside a movieclip are available in any frame onward from when they are defined (and even when it loops back around to frame 1 they'll still be available, even if they weren't declared on frame 1, though best practice would be to declare in the first frame).

So basically...your problem shouldn't really exist. Just store your data in a variable declared on frame 1. The only way your problem would exist is if you only had that variable inside the function itself so it was local to only that function...which would be an issue regardless of movieclips and keyframes.

Just don't do that. Declare the variable outside the function, use it inside the function.

```
// put this on frame 1
var speed = 1; // this will be accessible anywhere in the clip

// put this wherever your button appears (I assume on frame 1 as well)
yourBtnName.onRelease = function() {
    speed = 1.5; // the change will be refleced anywhere that uses it
}

// put this on some other frame and call it at any point
function doSomething() {
    trace(speed); // before clicking the button this will trace 1, after 1.5
}
```